# How do I add my Google Apps Script signature code within my Google Forms

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-apps-script, google-forms

I found this code online, and it allows me to draw signaures with .gs and .html.

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}
function saveToDrive(signature){
  var signature = signature.split(",")
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(signature[1]), 'image/png');
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.insertImage(blob, 1, 1);
}
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/></head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/willowsystems/jSignature/master/libs/jSignature.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <form>
    ...
    Signature:
    <div id="signature"></div><br>
    <img id="rendered" src="" style="display:none">
    <input type="Submit" value="Save" onclick="getSignature();"/>
    ...
    </form>
    </body>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("signature").style.border = "1px solid black";
      $("#signature").jSignature({
        'background-color': 'transparent',
        'decor-color': 'transparent'
      });
      function getSignature(){
        $("img#rendered").attr("src",$('#signature').jSignature('getData','default'));
        var signature = document.getElementById('rendered').src;
        google.script.run.saveToDrive(signature);
      } 
    </script>
    </html>
```

I just want to know how I intergrate it within my form, so that at the bottom, there is a place to sign, which then automatically saves to my google drive as a jpg, and is shown in my form as an image.

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: Yes of course you can

Answer (score 1):

### You can adjust the code snippet to save the signature to your Drive and embed the WebApp URL in your form

For this:

- Modify the `saveToDrive` function to

```
function saveToDrive(signature){
  var signature = signature.split(",")
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(signature[1]), 'image/png');
  blob.setName("signature");
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}
```

- Deploy your code as a WebApp with the settings: `Execute the app as:`  `Me`, `Who has access to the app:` `Anyone, even anonymous`.
- Now, I am not aware of a way to embed this WebApp into a Google form (you would need to create a custom HTML form for this), but what you can do is to provide a link to the WebApp as part of a question / response option and kindly ask the user to follow the link.

Here is a sample form (keep in mind that the WebApp is deployed as me, so if you provide a signature, it will be saved on my Drive and not yours ):

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSckCxKzrUdNvpcONLVRvJ08e5EDZRNB-tTfSRKG2YRLVjI_Ww/viewform

Comment: Note that asking people to go to a random webapp is going to make a very scary popup where it isn't obvious how to execute it (you have to click the blue link at the bottom) so users will be hesitant to do this. You might be better off if the entire form was a webapp since you need one any way to do it like this, but again, scary google security popups.

Comment: This is true. It's probably best to create a custom Html form - with or without a Webapp where the signature field would be nicely embedded within the form.

Comment: I wish google just had this feature pre-built haha. I like the webapp Idea, but I'd need a database to store the results, and I also need to automate the responses to be sent to the email address of the "Enter email" field. If anyone knows how I should go about this, please let me know. I'm a massive noob

Comment: Also on line 8 "var signature = signature.split(",")" I get an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined". Any ideas why?

Comment: This usually means that no valid signature has been uploaded, did you hit the submit button without signing? Implementing some logs and conditional statements both client and service side is helpful.